# load Data from local store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, store, local

I'm facing some diffculties loading specific data records frome local store into app's views.

The store looks like this:

```
Ext.define('xyz.store.UserDataStore', { extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [ 'xyz.model.user' ],

config: { 
   autoLoad: true, 
   autoSync: true, 
   model: 'xyz.model.user', 
   storeId: 'myStore', 
   proxy: { type: 'localstorage', id: 'id' } } });
```

The model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('xyz.model.user', { extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: { fields: [ { name: 'token', type: 'string' }, { name: 'title' }, { name: 'login' }, { name: 'facebookId' }, { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' }, { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' }, { name: 'nationality', type: 'string' }, { name: 'birthDay', type: 'string' }, { name: 'phone' }, { name: 'mobile' }, { name: 'street' }, { name: 'city', type: 'string' }, { name: 'zipCode', type: 'int' }, { name: 'willingToTravel' }, { name: 'pictureUrl' }, { name: 'eMail' }, { name: 'publicList' } ] } });
```

Thank you in advance,
Sabine

Comment: That's some SenchaTouch code, isn't it? What are you trying to achieve? Put some data in the store? Where does this data come from?

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes it is. After the login, the data is loaded from a server into the store automatically. Now I like to pick some specific data record (e.g. "nationality") to put it in a certain dataview.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. You should add the code for your view, and point to the precise step where you're blocked...

Comment: With this code I can acces my store:
Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore');

Now I like to get the Username out of the Store:

var username = userstore.???();
Which code hast to replace "???" to acchieve this?